# Time-consuming task recovery in docker swarm cluster

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, docker-swarm

Our application contains a lot of micro-service(independent application most of which are java based) which are deployed in docker swarm cluster, and each service can be scaled at runtime, even the whole stack may restart sometimes too.

However  when remove or restart a certain service, there maybe some time-consuming tasks running inside the right container. For example:

1. Container remove/restart when a large fill is being uploaded.
2. Container remove/restart when data are being imported from a uploaded file which is saved in the `/tmp` dir inside the container.
3. Container remove/restart when index are being created for a certain data table.
4. ....

We must recover them as soon as possible. Take the above suitation as example:

1. Can not be recovered, use have to upload the file again.
2. Should be recovered, restart the import job from where it is terminated.
3. The same as 2.

Sounds like we need a distribution framework which can persist all tasks status, check the healthy of each task, recover when required.

Any lightweight solution can be suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Task orchestration between different services is never really lightweight IMO, and implementing a change such as that could be allot of work & very difficult for the organisation you work for to grasp (I'll explain later).

We are going through this process right now, we first tried to do this with Spring Batch, but like you we needed this to be distributed across multiple services and highly available, so we moved to using Step Functions in AWS.

You can still develop locally but use Step Functions as well with a bit of work, I did this by implementing a fairly simple workflow for developers to make use of, which involved using their own private components on AWS (SQS queues) prepended by their `$USERNAME` variable. This should be as easy as setting some environment variables.

But the decision what orchestration framework to use should depend on a number of factors:

- Do you have one in place already you can use?
- What cloud provider if/are you using, do they have a solution?
- What expertise do your developers have, eg. if you are heavy on Python you might want to use a Python solution etc.

Whilst implementing an orchestration framework can be challenging, it's not really the most difficult part, YMMV. What I have found the most challenging is getting the business to decide on making different tradeoffs. Take recovery for example, maybe a task should be attempted again in 5 minutes time if something fails, which is pretty trivial to implement on a Step Function. But this could mean that a job takes longer to fail than it otherwise would before you implemented this, whilst jobs that were failing are now succeeding with the second attempt. I've found non-technical people don't understand or want to understand this, and will tell you that things should both fail fast, and recover at the same time when these configurations compete with each other. Who owns this process too? If it effects more than just your team that will again be tricky and you might have different teams with competing priorities.